# ReactJs material ui styles broken when build was deployed

Tags: reactjs, build, material-ui

I build my app developed using material ui of reactjs but the styles are broken on deployed build version
 this is my App.JS file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import DateFnsUtils from 'material-ui-pickers/utils/date-fns-utils';
import MuiPickersUtilsProvider from 'material-ui-pickers/utils/MuiPickersUtilsProvider';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import createHistory from 'history/createHashHistory';

import Home from './pages/home/Home';

const history = createHistory();

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
            <Router history={history}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

index.JS

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Above is my index.js file

Comment: can you show the code of the component where you have ReactDOM.render

Comment: @DhavalChheda I have added my index.js file also

Comment: you have no console warnings or errors correct?

Comment: @DhavalChheda yes nothing in console

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue, looks perfectly on development but different on build. There's an official solution for this:
[JSS Provider](https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#jssprovider)

Basically the main cause is the way class name is being generated, and somehow the library you are using has peer dependencies with each other, causing class name to overlap.